# bug in hangman game

Tags: java

So, I've successfully made a very simple but complete version of hangman. Now I want to refine the program and slowly add features (eventually graphics I hope). The first thing I'd like to fix has to do with repeating letters, at this point, If the user decided to type the same letter (one that IS in the word) as many times as the length of the word, they would get a false "win". What's the best way to stop this from happening?

ps. I'm new to programming, this project was really hard for me...so if the answer is really obvious, sorry for asking, I just can't think anymore tonight.

any help would be greatly appreciated, here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class hangman_test2 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        boolean Lets_play=true;
        String response;

        while (Lets_play)
        {
            printheader();

            String the_word=getWord();

            System.out.println(the_word);
            print_blanks(the_word);     

            guesses(the_word);

            System.out.println("Want to play again?");
            response=in.readLine();
            if(response.charAt(0)=='n' || response.charAt(0)=='N')
            {
                Lets_play= false;
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
            }
        }
    }//end main


    public static void printheader()
    {
    System.out.println("Welcome, lets play hangman!");
    System.out.println("enter letters to guess the word\n");
    }//end print header

    public static String getWord()
    {

        String [] possible_word=new String [10];


        possible_word[0]="green";
        possible_word[1]="orange";
        possible_word[2]="tree";
        possible_word[3]="flowers";
        possible_word[4]="ocean";
        possible_word[5]="grudge";
        possible_word[6]="scraple";
        possible_word[7]="crab";
        possible_word[8]="insect";
        possible_word[9]="stripes";


        String theWord= possible_word [(int)(Math.random()*possible_word.length)];
        return theWord;
    }//end the word

    public static void print_blanks(String the_word)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<the_word.length(); x++)
        {
            System.out.print("_ ");
        }

    }//print blanks

    public static void guesses(String the_word)throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        boolean thisRound=true;
        int strike=0;


        int right_letter=0;


        while (thisRound)
        {

            int letters_not_in_word=0;

            char letter_guessed=in.readLine().charAt(0);


            for (int current_letter=0; current_letter<the_word.length(); current_letter++)
            {

                if (the_word.charAt(current_letter)==letter_guessed)


                {

                    System.out.println(letter_guessed + " fits in space number " + (current_letter+1));

                    right_letter++;


                    if(right_letter == the_word.length())
                    {

                        win(the_word);
                        thisRound=false;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    letters_not_in_word++;

                    if (letters_not_in_word==the_word.length())
                    {
                        System.out.println(letter_guessed + " is not in the word");
                        strike ++;

                        if(strike==5)
                        {
                            lose(the_word);
                            thisRound=false;
                        }

                    }//if

                }//else
            }//for

        }//while

    }//end guesses


    public static void win( String word)
    {
    System.out.println("\ncongradulations, you won!");
    System.out.println("the word is " + word + "\n");
    }

    public static void lose( String word)
    {
    System.out.println("\nsorry, you lost");
    System.out.println("the word is " + word + "\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: You are new to Java that's why I am telling u. You are not following proper naming conventions. Your class name "hangman_test2" should start with capital letter and there is no need to put _ in this like "HangmanTest2" and your variable name should start with small caps letter "letsPlay".

Comment: I haven't looked at the code yet, but couldn't you set it so that if they enter more than one character, then only give them a win if what they entered is the word?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and the Set interface. What a Set does is to prevent adding the same object twice.

So every time the user adds a letter, check if it's already in the set. If it isn't, then check their guess and add it to the set. If it is already in the set, then ignore their guess.

Comment: This also has the benefit of preventing the user from guessing the same wrong letter multiple times.

Comment: Gnat - that sounds like a good suggestion, I'll definitely try it out tomorrow morning and be sure to accept your answer if it works out.